# Angular 2: why use switchMap when retrieving route params?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm reading the [Angular Guide about Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

They use this code for retrieving the router's param `'id'` and using it to get a hero with the `service` service:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.getHero(+params['id']))
    .subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);
}
```

But I do not well understand what is the purpose of using the `switchMap` operator in the above code.

The following code would not be the same?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    // NOTE: I do not use switchMap here, but subscribe directly
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.service.getHero(+params['id']).then(hero => this.hero = hero)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`switchMap` is usually used when you have some async operation that is triggered by some prepended "event/stream".

The difference to e.g. `flatMap` or `concatMap` is, that as soon as the next trigger emits, the current async operation is canceled and re-triggered.

In your case this means, that as soon as the route-params change, your hero-service is automatically called again with the changed params and the previous call is canceled so you won't receive outdated data.

This is especially helpful for search-queries that might take longer then 200-300ms and are triggered while a user is typing.

> The following code would not be the same?

No. While it might behave the same in many cases, if you imagine the following scenario:

1. param changes to "4"
2. `getHero(4)` (a very slow request)
3. param changes to "1"
4. `getHero(1)` (a fast request)
5. `getHero(1)` completes -> hero is "1"
6. `getHero(4)` completes -> hero is now "4" but the last used param was "1"

In such a case `switchMap` would just discard the `getHero(4)`-call since it is outdated as soon as a new trigger happens.

Comment: That is very well explained! One question, does the inner subscription have to be returned e.g. either implicitly by not using brackets in the arrow function or with (params)=>{ return .... }

Comment: `() => {...}` will return type void by default. With switchMap you must return an Observable.